# Aws Elastic Beanstalk diskspaceutilization metric alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using many ElasticBeanstalk environments and I'd like to monitor disk utilization.
I've configured custom options to send logs to cloudwatch:

```
custom_options: CloudWatchMetrics: --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --disk-space-util --disk-space-used --disk-space-avail --disk-path=/ --auto-scaling
```

I'd like to create alarm based od DiskSpaceUtilization metric but encountered problem that
InstanceID is changing after deploying new version of application.
The way I can solve it when creating alarms is to use AutoscalingGroupName instead of InstanceID, but that metric was created only on two of my Environments. What may be the reason that other environments do not create metrics in autoscalinggroups, but only as instanceid?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using mon-put-instance-data.pl from aws-scripts-mon, and I added logging:
/opt/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --disk-space-util --disk-space-used --disk-space-avail --disk-path=/ --auto-scaling >> /var/log/cwpump.log 2>&1
I found problem:
WARNING: Failed to call EC2 to obtain Auto Scaling group name. HTTP Status Code: 403. Error Message: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

WARNING: The Auto Scaling metrics will not be reported this time.